How can I customise view page of a list in SharePoint designer 2019 on prem?
I have created a calendar view with my list for a meeting room site. I want to customise the page (Like adding room type filtration, pretty UI etc.). Is there a way I can do this?
I have tried adding html page to the .aspx page, but it didn't work.
Please share how I can do so?
